# RigidBody.MovePosition won't stop even after reaching the destination

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, rigid-bodies

I am creating an elevator of which constantly moves from Point A to Point B.
I cannot just use `transform.position ( location here * speed here etc)` since I have a player that has a `Rigidbody`, and if using that it would flicker my player out whenever I am on the elevator. I also tried parenting the Player whenever its on the elevator (and de-parents it when it jumps etc), that fixes the flickering however it somewhat bugs the player's jumping mechanism.

Last resort is using a `Rigidbody` to my elevator and moves it with this code:

```c#
private void FixedUpdate() 
{
    Vector2 l_mypos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    Vector2 l_target = new Vector2(_targetPoint.position.x, _targetPoint.position.y);
    if (l_mypos != l_target)
    {
        MoveElevator(l_target);
        Debug.Log(l_mypos + " - " + l_target);
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("reached");
}

private void MoveElevator(Vector2 toTarget)
{
    Vector2 direction = (toTarget - (Vector2)transform.position).normalized;
    _elevatorRB.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + direction * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This moves the elevator towards the direction given, however it doesn't reach the "reached" condition. I placed a debug.log there to see both `mpos` and `target` to see the differences. It ends with `0, 10, 0 - 0, 10, 0` meaning both my target and the elevator's position is already the same. However it doesn't reach the else condition, and the elevator keeps flickering at Point B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`==` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-operator_eq.html) for `Vector2` uses an estimation of `0.00001` for equality.

However it is very possible that you overshoot the target in

```csharp
(Vector2)transform.position + direction * _speed * Time.deltaTime
```

since your final velocity `speed * Time.deltaTime` is certainly greater than `0.00001`. (Except your `speed` is smaller than `0.0006` which I doubt.)

The value you see in the `Debug.Log` is the result of a `Vector3.ToString` which uses human readable rounded values and does not show the actually `float` values! From the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector3.cs)

```csharp
public override string ToString()
{
    return ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
}

public string ToString(string format)
{
    return ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
}

public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) format = "F1"; // <- !! HERE !!

    return UnityString.Format("({0}, {1}, {2})", x.ToString(format, formatProvider), y.ToString(format, formatProvider), z.ToString(format, formatProvider));
}
```

---

You should rather use [`Vector2.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.MoveTowards.html) which avoids this overshooting.

The API of [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) actually explains it better then the one of `Vector2.MoveTowards`

> Calculate a position between the points specified by `current` and `target`, moving no farther than the distance specified by `maxDistanceDelta`.
>
> Use the `MoveTowards` member to move an object at the `current` position toward the `target` position. By updating an object’s position each frame using the position calculated by this function, you can move it towards the target smoothly. Control the speed of movement with the `maxDistanceDelta` parameter. If the `current` position is already closer to the `target` than `maxDistanceDelta`, the value returned is equal to `target`; **the new position does not overshoot target**. To make sure that object speed is independent of frame rate, multiply the `maxDistanceDelta` value by `Time.deltaTime`

```csharp
private void FixedUpdate() 
{
     // Vector3 and Vector2 have implicit operators allowing to use
     // both types exchangeably. 
     // In order actively to convert them you can simply typecast between them
     var l_mypos = (Vector2) transform.position;
     var l_target = (Vector2) _targetPoint.position;

     if (l_mypos != l_target)
     {
         MoveElevator(l_target);
         Debug.Log(l_mypos + " - " + l_target);
     }
     else
     {
         Debug.Log("reached");
     }
}

private void MoveElevator(Vector2 toTarget)
{
    var pos = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, toTarget, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    _elevatorRB.MovePosition(pos);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for making a good answer. I also have learned something :)

Comment: I have solved it using Rigidbody and rigidbody.MoveTowards. However thanks a lot for the answer it was still very informative! :)